# factory_girl_rails & Cucumber::undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, factory-bot

Having a problem with making this work. Seems it has been a problem for others and I think I have followed all of the advice.

I've set up a stripped down rails 3 .0.14 app to just include cucumber-rails & factory_girl_rails but still no go. I expect I am doing something silly!

Running the cuc test below produces the following:

```
Scenario: test factory-girl        # features/users.feature:3
  Given the following user exists: # features/users.feature:4
    | name    | email               |
    | Brandon | brandon@example.com |
    Undefined step: "the following user exists:" (Cucumber::Undefined)
```

The user factory has been created, of which I am sure, with a bit of 'pp' output.
Would really appreciate any help to get this sorted.

Ross

**Set up**

*env.rb: snippet*

```
require 'pp'
require 'cucumber/rails'

require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'factory_girl/step_definitions'
```

*features/support/factories.rb:*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Adam Advertiser'
    email 'a@b.com'still
  end   
end
pp FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

*Cucumber features/user.feature:*

```
Feature: a
  Scenario: test factory-girl
    Given the following user exists:
    | name    | email               |
    | Brandon | brandon@example.com |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have to get your factory required *before* requiring 'factory_girl/step_definitions', because there is meta-programming in step_definitions which needs to know about your factory. You could explicitly require the factories.rb in the env.rb, but that will end up producing a duplicate definition error, as cucumber will re-require factories.rb.

You need to remove the requiring of step_definitions from the env.rb - that will make it happen too early - and put it at the bottom of factories.rb, or else create a wrapper which requires first the factories (which will need to reside somewhere that cucumber doesn't automatically require) and then the step_definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. env.rb now looks like this:`require 'pp'
require 'cucumber/rails'

require 'factory_girl_rails' and factories.rb looks like this `FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :user do
  name 'Adam Advertiser'
  email 'a@b.com'
 end
 
end
pp FactoryGirl.create(:user)

require 'factory_girl/step_definitions'` which is hopefully what you were suggesting. The alternative you mentioned is a little beyond my current level. Anyway, the steps are now recognised but not quite right because I get a "Factory not registered: user (ArgumentError)". Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
`

Comment: Sorry - had to do it again -- Thanks for the quick reply. **env.rb** now looks like this:
`require 'pp'
require 'cucumber/rails'
require 'factory_girl_rails'` 
and **factories.rb** looks like this:
`FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Adam Advertiser'
    email 'a@b.com'
  end
end
pp FactoryGirl.create(:user)
require 'factory_girl/step_definitions'` 
which is hopefully what you were suggesting. Factory_girl steps are now recognised but not quite right because I get a "**Factory not registered: user (ArgumentError)**". Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
`

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce this error, so I may not be of much more help. Here is a gist I created with the barebones version of my test app: < https://gist.github.com/1439759 > This should be all you need to make it work. If that exact file structure is not working for you, we must have a difference in environment? Please let me know what version of ruby and what versions of the various gems you are using. (The reason for the save! method is to avoid having to do something with persistence, to keep it a simple test case.)

Comment: Thank you for that. The only difference I could see is your explicit loading of the User model. Alas, it made difference. I've added gist [git://gist.github.com/1440592.git].
Ruby version is ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux].
System is: Linux cb-2 3.0.0-13-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 2 13:27:26 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I do hope that helps.